# Match two arrays based on location in text

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am looking for a way to parse a given text, and match two elements from two arrays. The first array holds Party names and it should match with the role that appears next in the text.

I have split the original text into an array, however some elements in the parties[] and roles[] have multiple words in them so it is difficult to find the parties location in the text

```
string text = "This is an example of the text to parse through, it has the title of role1. We want to extract data points like Party1 which is a role2 followed by Party2 which is a role3. Finally, we want to find Party3. This party is also known as role4. We want to display each party with its respective role";

string[] parties = {"Party1", "Party2", "Party3"};
string[] roles = {"role1", "role2", "role3", "role4"};
```

Result: `"Party1 = role2 \n Party2 = role3 \n Party3 = role4"`

Comment: Please post the code that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to walk through the string and find the index of each party. Once that index is found, find the index of the next role and save these to the string.

There are definite improvements that could be made, but it might help get you started:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "This is an example of the text to parse through, it has the title of role1. We want to extract data points like Party1 which is a role2 followed by Party2 which is a role3. Finally, we want to find Party3. This party is also known as role4. We want to display each party with its respective role";
    string[] parties = {"Party1", "Party2", "Party3"};
    string[] roles = {"role1", "role2", "role3", "role4"};

    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    int index = 0;

    foreach (var party in parties)
    {
        index = text.IndexOf(party, index);
        if (index <= -1) continue;

        var r = roles
            .Select(role => new {Role = role, Index = text.IndexOf(role, index)})
            .Where(i => i.Index > -1)
            .OrderBy(i => i.Index)
            .First();

        results.Add(r != null ? $"{party} = {r.Role}" : $"{party} = N/A");
        index = r?.Index ?? index;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" \n ", results));

    GetKeyFromUser("\n\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

[image]